# How do I import an svg in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, svg, vuejs3

I tried following:
https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/tree/master

but there's a version conflict with vue-template-compiler since that's used in Vue 2.

I tried:
https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader

but I'm missing a specific vue dependency.

I noticed there's a caveat with using typescript and you need to declare the type definition file. However, I still get "Cannot find module '../../assets/myLogo.svg' or its corresponding type declarations."

Here's what I added:

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => 
  {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg');

    svgRule.uses.clear();

    svgRule
      .use('vue-loader-v16')
      .loader('vue-loader-v16')
      .end()
      .use('vue-svg-loader')
      .loader('vue-svg-loader');
  },
  configureWebpack: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? {} : {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  },
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
    '/PersonalWebsite/' : '/'
}
```

shims-svg.d.ts

```
declare module '*.svg' {
  const content: any;
  export default content;
}
```

MyComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
     <MyLogo />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import * as MyLogo from "../../assets/myLogo.svg";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "MyComponent",
  components: {
    MyLogo
  },
  props: {
    
  },
  setup(props)
  {
    return {
      props
    };
  }
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually SVGs are supported right out of the box with Vue CLI. It uses [file-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) internally. You can confirm it by running the following command on the terminal:

```
vue inspect --rules
```

If "svg" is listed (it should be), then all you've got to do is:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <img :src="myLogoSrc" alt="my-logo" />
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  // Please just use `@` to refer to the root "src" directory of the project
  import myLogoSrc from "@/assets/myLogo.svg";

  export default defineComponent({
    name: "MyComponent",

    setup() {
      return {
        myLogoSrc
      };
    }
  });
</script>
```

So there's no need for any third party library—that is if your sheer purpose is only to display SVGs.

And of course, to satisfy the TypeScript compiler on the type declaration:

```js
declare module '*.svg' {
  // It's really a string, precisely a resolved path pointing to the image file
  const filePath: string;

  export default filePath;
}
```

Comment: it "works", but the compiled svg location shows the svg code, prepended with the following message: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Comment: I gave up and moved it to public otherwise, this seems like a decent option https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-svg-inline-plugin . This answer just copies the whole thing as a plain string... which works in zero browsers. If you're desperate you can convert that to a base64 data URI...

Comment: @RayFoss As I said, it's Vue CLI with file-loader. What is your setup? Your comment doesn't help others understand how this could fail those seeking answers.

Comment: @YomT. CodeSanbox's Vue 3 Template specifically https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-worker-fibonacci-9v1li

Comment: @RayFoss That seems to only prove further that it works right out of the box.

Comment: @RayFoss Even with this `console.clear()` removed, I still couldn't find any specific error concerning SVG rendering on the sandbox.

Comment: @YomT. ... Wrong ticket... I thought this was a thread about the Webpack build flags warning. In that sandbox I resorted to statically sourcing the svg, instead of having webpack mangle it the url into a raw string that wont work. if you move the svg to src or assets and try importing... you'll have a bad time.

Comment: Thanks this is magic and a much better solution that installing a third-part loader which is in beta (since 2020) for loading svg's

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman Are you viewing the SVG XML in a browser when you see that message? Have you checked the content of the compiled code in devtools?

Comment: it works in dev with `yarn serve` but doesn't in prod with `yarn build`

Comment: my issue was typescript related. this is a solution: https://github.com/damianstasik/vue-svg-loader/issues/136#issuecomment-804682687

Answer (score 4):

vue-svg-loader is not compatible with vue 3. To import svg and use it as a component, simply wrap the contents of the file in 'template'

In component:

```js
<template>
  <div class="title">
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span>
    <Icon />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Icon from '~/common/icons/icon.svg';

export default {
  name: 'PageTitle',
  components: { Icon },
};
</script>
```

Webpack:

```js
{
   test: /\.svg$/,
   use: ['vue-loader', path.resolve(__dirname, 'scripts/svg-to-vue.js')],
}
```

scripts/svg-to-vue.js:

```js
module.exports = function (source) {
  return `<template>\n${source}\n</template>`;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

It's true using an IMG tag will render your SVG, but for anyone expecting SVG features, you won't get that with an IMG tag. There's a more expanded tutorial here:
https://blog.logrocket.com/using-svg-and-vue-js-a-complete-guide/ (check out number 3)

But essentially, your best option for custom SVG's is to build them as a Vue Component and import that component. This will give you full flexibility in controlling stroke and fill properties as well as open up opportunities to pass in your Vue variables to effect changes to the SVG. Take a look at example 3 on that site.

The big thing this fixed for me was being able to pass the CSS color property to the SVG and then have the SVG stroke="currentColor" actually recognize it. When the SVG is loaded with an img tag that color modifier is never honored, I just end up with a black SVG.

Examples from my use (I needed a Tabler icon that wasn't in the Tabler Vue 3 library I'd imported)
So I went to https://tabler-icons.io/ and downloaded the one I wanted (alert-circle-filled in this case) which gave me the SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-alert-circle-filled" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
  <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
  <path d="M17 3.34a10 10 0 1 1 -14.995 8.984l-.005 -.324l.005 -.324a10 10 0 0 1 14.995 -8.336zm-4.99 11.66l-.127 .007a1 1 0 0 0 0 1.986l.117 .007l.127 -.007a1 1 0 0 0 0 -1.986l-.117 -.007zm-.01 -8a1 1 0 0 0 -.993 .883l-.007 .117v4l.007 .117a1 1 0 0 0 1.986 0l.007 -.117v-4l-.007 -.117a1 1 0 0 0 -.993 -.883z" stroke-width="0" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>
```

I then built this component, which is just really a wrapper for the SVG from that:

```
<template>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-alert-circle-filled" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="2" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round">
  <path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/>
  <path d="M17 3.34a10 10 0 1 1 -14.995 8.984l-.005 -.324l.005 -.324a10 10 0 0 1 14.995 -8.336zm-4.99 11.66l-.127 .007a1 1 0 0 0 0 1.986l.117 .007l.127 -.007a1 1 0 0 0 0 -1.986l-.117 -.007zm-.01 -8a1 1 0 0 0 -.993 .883l-.007 .117v4l.007 .117a1 1 0 0 0 1.986 0l.007 -.117v-4l-.007 -.117a1 1 0 0 0 -.993 -.883z" stroke-width="0" fill="currentColor" />
</svg>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   name: 'AlertCircleFilled',
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.icon-tabler-alert-circle-filled {
    /* Scoped CSS here */
}
</style>
```

Lastly, I just import and use the Vue component, and now my CSS color is correctly used by the SVG:

```
import AlertCircleFilledIcon from './AlertCircleFilled.vue';
...
components: {AlertCircleFilledIcon, ... },
...
<AlertCircleFilledIcon class="btnIcon" style="color:blue;"/>
```

Comment: Best answer IMO

Answer (score 1):

Can't say for sure, since I haven't tried with ts, but as posted [here](https://github.com/visualfanatic/vue-svg-loader/issues/136#issuecomment-724205887)

this should work.

```
declare module '*.svg' {
    import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue';
    const component: DefineComponent;
    export default component;
}
```

I see you're using:

```js
import * as MyLogo from "../../assets/myLogo.svg";
```

I believe that should be:

```js
import MyLogo from "../../assets/myLogo.svg";
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but it's saying it can't find the DefineComponent type. "Module '"../node_modules/vue/dist/vue"' has no exported member 'DefineComponent'. Did you mean 'defineComponent'?" defineComponent is not a type.

Comment: changing the import to: "import MyLogo From "../../assets/myLogo.svg" I get the following error. VM117:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/img/myLogo.0b631187.svg') is not a valid name.

Answer (score 0):

Example from fresh installed vue.js 3.2:

```
<img alt="Vue logo" class="logo" src="@/assets/logo.svg" width="125" height="125"/>
```